# RegularExpression in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

How to write Regular Expression which can find this

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:setSectionName('');showFunctionMenu2( ......>xxxxxx</a>
```

and replace the same with

```
<a href="#" style="display:none;" onclick="javascript:setSectionName('');showFunctionMenu2( ......>xxxxxx</a>
```

in html document using Javascript?

I came up with this to find but dont know how to replace the same with new one in html

```
<a\shref\="\#"\sonclick\="javascript\:setSectionName\(''\)\;showFunctionMenu2\(.+><\/a>
```

Comment: In other cases, I would recommend using a DOM parser. But here, the you actually have a fully functioning, deeply integrated DOM parser inherent to the problem... and you still want to use regexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery filter

```
$('a').filter(function(index) { 
  return (this.onclick.match(/setSectionName\(''\);showFunctionMenu2\(/) !== null);
});
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/<a href="#" onclick="[^"]*"/>.*?</a>/
```